# Loading data only once in Android with ViewModel

Tags: java, android, kotlin, viewmodel

I have an Android app with a main fragment that you can navigate from using navigation graph. Data is loaded when the main fragment is opened. The problem is when I navigate from it and go back the data is loaded again, because fragment is recreated. How is it possible to load data only once?

Comment: We'll need to see some code to know what's wrong. It really depends on what kind of repository is backing up your data.

Comment: If your function that loads data is in `onCreateView` or a lifecycle method called after a new View is created you can try to move it to one such as `onCreate`

Comment: But the Fragment is recreated every time. Is there a way to know if it was created the first time or it was recreated?

Comment: You can cache the data in view model so you won't need to load data again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewModel with the app and make a check if the ViewModel is already created do not load the data again

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use SingleLiveEvent it will fix your problem please check this

[Medium](https://abhiappmobiledeveloper.medium.com/android-singleliveevent-of-livedata-for-ui-event-35d0c58512da)

[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266324/how-to-use-single-live-event-to-show-toast-in-kotlin)