# LiveData starts Fragment twice on rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I have a project which contains one activity and one fragment. The activity observes a LiveData variable, and when the variable is a certain value it shows a fragment.

```java
// Activity onCreate
mViewModel.getConnectionState().observe(this, state -> {
  if (state == 3) { // example
    mMyFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
  }
});
```

However, I notice that when the fragment is active, and I rotate the screen, the fragment is recreated, and also the LiveData gets triggered again due to the activity being recreated, which launches the fragment a second time. what's the best way to handle this so that the fragment is only recreated once?

Comment: You can use `SingleLiveEvent`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266324/how-to-use-single-live-event-to-show-toast-in-kotlin).